# iOS7 use a restoration class separate from ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been going the [iOS app programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html) and the tutorial [Creating the Restoration Class](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_State_Preservation_and_Restoration_Tutorial#Creating_the_Restoration_Class) and reading how to save and restore view controllers and data in views controllers. However I've hit a problem.

I want to restore the data in my login screen, the first view controller that is called - so I can't make it it's own restoration class. The website says to implement the `application:viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:coder:` in my app delegate. However if I do this I can't use `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` or `decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` to save or restore values in the text fields.

I also can't make my second view controller a self restoration classes as it implements a delegate  so can't do the same for `<UIViewControllerRestoration>`.

**How do I create separate restoration classes that I can save the state and data of my view controllers in?**

Currently I have implemented shouldSaveApplicationState and shouldRestoreApplicationState in my App Delegate and set restoration identifiers on my view controllers and text fields.

Comment: If it's the first view controller it doesn't really make sense to restore it since it will be shown anyway. Couldn't you just save the data in NSUserDefaults and populate your login screen the next time the app is started?

Comment: Edit: Googling it now
I'd like to add that I am new to restoration stuff and the giant walls of text I've had to read are quite overwhelming. I apologise if any of my questions seem silly.

Comment: Not a problem. I think with a simple app you don't really need to worry about the restoration stuff, so if it's too much you should focus on learning the other stuff first. And still, you don't need automatic restoration for the first screen anyway.

Comment: One more thing - the restoration API's are ONLY for returning your app to where you were the last time after it restarts, and you should NOT use them to store your data. For this, you should consider using NSUserDefaults, SQLite or Core Data.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've found a tutorial for NSUSerDefaults although it appears to be a couple of years old. I'll post up if I have any issues. How secure is NSUserDefaults for storing password information? Is it safe or do I have to do anything else to make the stored data secure?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is for preferences and should not be considered secure. For passwords, use the keychain (see http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html)

Comment: Cheers. I've had a look into keychain, but including the libraries gives me build errors. I made a post about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320490/xctest-xctest-h-file-not-found-xcode-5-1-1-ios7